# SceneKit - Render certain nodes always in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, scenekit

Is it possible to force certain nodes to render before other nodes?

E.g. I have a sphere that is moving inside a plane and I want the sphere to be always on top of the plane. At the moment half / parts of the plane sometimes flicker on top of the sphere.

I tried using the renderingOrder property of SCNNode but that didn't help.

Comment: Hi sorry to hijack an old question but did you ever find a solution for this?